# Getting `**TEST SUCCEEDED**` from `xcodebuild` even with failed tests

Tags: xcode, testing, xcodebuild, xctest, kiwi

I'm running this command to run my tests:

```
xcodebuild -workspace WORKSOPACE.xcworkspace -scheme MY_SCHEME -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 -configuration Debug clean build test
```

I'm getting this output in the end when I have failing tests:

```
Test Suite 'TESTS-TARGET-NAME.xctest' failed at 2014-12-03 08:59:00 +0000.
     Executed 87 tests, with 1 failure (1 unexpected) in 2.220 (2.225) seconds
Test Suite 'All tests' failed at 2014-12-03 08:59:00 +0000.
     Executed 87 tests, with 1 failure (1 unexpected) in 2.220 (2.226) seconds
** TEST SUCCEEDED **
```

I'm using Xcode6 with Cocoapods, my tests library is Kiwi (XCTest), and I haven't created a special scheme just for tests (since that tests are working properly, besides the final output).

**UPDATE**:
This actually works well on a colleague computer. This has been run on the same repo and supposingly same configurations, which is why I suspect something is wrong locally with my local xcode configuration (don't know what though).

Comment: Have You tried checking command exit code, e.g. with `echo $?`? What the status?

Comment: Yes, the status is 0.

Comment: AFAIK that is just telling you that the tests have finished running. It's weird but it seems to be the Xcode way.

Comment: Seems to me that something is wrong. How can a CI server know that my build has failed then?